# Use of backgroundworker is good when your thread may have to wait for long time

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, .net-3.5, backgroundworker

My winform application requires to query database (via stored procedures) frequently to retrieve any new updates. This is currently done through background worker thread. The problem is that sometimes stored procedures takes a long time which means (per my understanding ) that we are wasting threadpool thread resource as all its doing is just waiting for db call to complete. I was just wondering if there are any better ways of handling this (something like APM begin/end type of calls)?

Comment: Show us your code so we know what you tried so far.

Comment: I am using standard backgroundworker pattern implementing DoWork, RunWorkerCompleted etc events. My question is more related to pattern than code because whatever is been done in the DoWork is calling a stored procedure that is taking long time which is probably waste of threadpool thread. I am asking if there are any better way of handling this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BeginExecuteReader` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make an asynchronous datebase call.